# What the best practices to place ads in a website?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, html, design-patterns, seo

I want place ads in my website, but I'm unsure about the common practices to place thes ads.
By example, some cool asp.net articles sites shows ads in the middle of the article! So you read 2-3 paragraphs, read some ad, then finish the article reading...

Another worry is about sabotage. One of mine customers get their Google adsense account banned, due some rival that clicked a lot of times in the goodle ads... there is some javascript techniques to block *[edit] the undesirable click flood! [/edit]*?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Google (unsurprisingly) knows a fair amount about where people look on a page. They have [an article about where to place ads](https://www.google.com/adsense/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=17954).

Personally, I have the ads on my C# articles right at the bottom - by the time you get there, you've received all the benefit of the page already. That way I don't feel I'm disrupting my users. Then again, I'm not really trying to make significant money from them.

Comment: I don't _like_ upvoting JS, but I like his attitude here. ;-)

Comment: @Peter: If it's any consolation, your vote has made no difference to my rep :)

Comment: ;-) Good to hear. I can live with myself again. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

I find the ads in the middle of an article to be very annoying. Avoid this if possible. Place the ads on sides and top, but remember to leave plenty of space for contents too. Remember that >90% users will come for the contents anyway and will not care for the ads no matter where you put them. Those who want them, will spot them on the sides just as easily. But those who don't (and that's the vast majority) will just be very annoyed if the ads bother them - thus less likely to come back to your site.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to get heat for this, but: *The absolute best practise is to not place any ads on there at all*.

Answer (score 1):

> goodle ads... there is some javascript
>   techniques to block this?

I would not try to do such a thing because this count as sabotage too. Just let the inserted Adsense code be.

I like the ads placement of *stackoverflow*:

- They do not bother you at all
- They are created with taste and make you curious
- Not to mention they are targeted

Comment: sorry if I wasn't clear. I want block the "click flood" attack.